# Resolving undefined symbols in .so that are defined in header

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

```
+-CMakeLists.txt
 | 
 +---Dir1
   |- source_file1.c
   |- CMakeLists.txt
 +---Dir2
   |- source_file2.c
   |- CMakeLists.txt
 +---Dir3
   |- header_file.h
```

I have a shared library abc.so created using cmake

This library has 2 undefined names:

```
U do_something1
U do_something2
```

both of which are defined in a Headerfile.h in a different directory. This file is part of the SOURCE_FILE for the source_file1.c and source_file2.c

However I am not able to get the undefined symbols resolved in the library! This is super wierd. What am I doing wrong?

Code is compile with -fPIC -rdynamic.
For some reason -Wl --export-all-symbols comes up as unrecognized from the compiler. The compiler is gcc 5.4.0

Comment: `both of which are defined in a Headerfile.h` - *dynamic* symbols are rarely defined in **header** files. If a function is *defined* in a header file, it normally uses `static inline` specifier. So, what to you mean by defining symbol in the `header_file.h`?

Comment: The two functions are inline functions. I see that all other non-inline functions are are defined in .so properly. How do I fix it? I do not want to keep them inline. Would adding static inline specifier fix it?

Comment: I kind of removed the inline functions and replaced the it with code directly for them now. So cannot immediately try it.

Comment: If `source_file1.c` include `header_file.h`, which defines `do_something1` function as `static inline`, this function shouldn't be "unknown" for the resulted library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Declaring the inline function as static fixed the issue.
b. If the c file includes the header with static inline that is enough

Thanks (@Tsyvarev)